# Password protect entire site depending on domain?

Tags: security, synchronization, .htpasswd

I have a development and production site that are both public on the Internet. I want to make the development server locked down.

I was told to use `.htpasswd` to put a password on the root web directory on the development server to restrict public access.

The problem is, my current workflow syncs everything between the production and development servers. Files, server settings, etc. I do this to ensure that the production server behaves as expected.

So the problem is if I set up .htpasswd on the dev, after syncing, the production server will be password protected as well.

So I was wondering if there is a way to make `.htpasswd` domain specific or if there is a better way of doing this all together?

Comment: How do you "sync" the servers? Can you apply a filter to file names (such as dot files, like .htpasswd) in that process? I have never found it useful to directly sync .htpasswd because of environmental differences, so our sync excludes it. I use BeanStalkApp.com to publish and simply leave the .htpasswd out of the version control system, using template.htpasswd instead to track changes.

Comment: I currently use rsync, I supposed I could use `--exclude=/var/www/.htpasswd` ...didn't even think of that.

Answer (score 2):

You sync ***everything*** between development and production? That is definitely not best practice (do you have change approval processes?). On topic, what are you using to sync? Just put an exclusion in to avoid copying the .htpassword files over. Or alternatively, create separate virtual hosts for your development and production and secure the development virtual host, while leaving the production untouched.

Comment: If I do not have the .htpasswd file on the production server, but the .htaccess file is synced, would that create an issue since the .htaccess file points to the .htpasswd file?

Comment: Yes it would. The presence of an .htaccess file will cause Apache to attempt to load access directives, which will fail due to the missing .htpasswd file. You want to include both files in your exclusion filter.

Comment: @Percertion, I need the .htaccess file though it does other mod_rewrite stuff that is needed.

Comment: Well that complicates things. And I assume you want to keep the .htaccess on production and development synced in case you make development changes? In which case defining virtual hosts for dev/prod might be the only option left.

Comment: Do you mean set 1 server as a shared server for dev and production .. that sounds like it might actually make syncing easier .. when you say secure the dev vhost do you mean via htpasswd or some other means?